# Xtext - No viable alternative at input

Tags: java, xtext

i'm trying to create a grammar that join togheter a script language with the possibility to create method.

**Grammar**

```
grammar org.example.domainmodel.Domainmodel with org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.Xbase

generate domainmodel "http://www.example.org/domainmodel/Domainmodel"

import "http://www.eclipse.org/xtext/xbase/Xbase" as xbase


Model:
    imports = XImportSection
    methods += XMethodDeclaration*
    body = XBlockScriptLanguage;

XMethodDeclaration:
    "def" type=JvmTypeReference name=ValidID 
    '('(params+=FullJvmFormalParameter (',' params+=FullJvmFormalParameter)*)? ')'
        body=XBlockExpression
;

XBlockScriptLanguage returns xbase::XExpression:
    {xbase::XBlockExpression}
        (expressions+=XExpressionOrVarDeclaration ';'?)*
;
```

At the moment i create the following JvmModelInferr, for defining the main method for scripting language.

**JvmModelInferr**

```
def dispatch void infer(Model model, IJvmDeclaredTypeAcceptor acceptor, boolean isPreIndexingPhase) {
        acceptor.accept(
            model.toClass("myclass")
        ).initializeLater [
                members += model.toMethod("main", model.newTypeRef(Void::TYPE)) [                       
                    parameters += model.toParameter("args", model.newTypeRef(typeof(String)).addArrayTypeDimension)
                    setStatic(true)
                    body = model.body

                    ]
            ]
    }
```

When i tryed to use my grammar, i obtain the following error after that i wrote my method:

- no viable alternative at input 'def'
- The method mymethod() is undefined

The problem is related only with method declaration, without it myclass.java is created.
Moreover i obtain the "Warning 200" for a not clear grammar, why?

Comment: How does your definition for `XImportSection` look? It seems like it's not optional, and your example does not have any imports. Maybe that's the problem.

Comment: Please add the example code you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

There are two fixes that appear necessary:

1. The `imports` section is not marked as optional. If it was intended to be optional, it should be declared as `imports ?= XImportSection`. Or, add necessary import statements to your JvmModelInferr example.
2. The `dispatch` keyword isn't defined in your grammar. As defined, a `method` should consist of `def`, followed by a Java type (the return type), and then the method's name (then the body, etc.). You could add `(dispatch ?= 'dispatch') if you're targeting Xtend and intend to support its multiple dispatch feature (or your own version of it).

HTH

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. The code shown at the bottom is not what he tries to parse, it's part of his JvmModelInferrer.